# Ubuntu 20.04: Can't' access to the display option on "Parameters"

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

I just got a PC with Ubuntu 20.04, and I want to use it with another screen. I connected the two with HDMI, but it doesn't work. When I want to get to the Display in Parameters, it isn't there. I don't have the “display” option.

I tried apt remove/ install gnome-control-center and unity-control-center, but I still don't get the display option, so I can't tell my Ubuntu to use another screen.

Do you have any idea how I could make my second screen to work or have access to the Display option? When I right-click on my desktop there is “display configuration” and when I click on it, it opens “Screens” in the Parameters, but I can't tell to display on my second screen there. See the picture here:

[image]

I really need to have this second screen working, since it is for work. Thanks!

PS: My mic doesn't work either! I feel like it's a problem related to drivers??

Comment: Some notebooks have dedicated hardware buttons to enable/disable the external monitor, for example [Fn]+[F8]. What brand and model of computer are you using?

Comment: I have the Dell Inspirion. I can see that there is what you're talking about on the F8 but it does nothing when I do [Fn]+[F8] or just [F8].

Answer (score 0):

Tests:

- HDMI cable: do you can test your hdmi cable?
  Boot:
- halt your pc. plug your hdmi and start for automatically detection
- in bios, change the video display by default and change for external, reboot for test your pc.

Comment: My HDMI cable is okay because it works when I'm on Windows but not on Linux. How do I start for automatically detection? How do I change the video display by default?